# CABasicAnimation manual progress from UISlider

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to achieve a simple behaviour:

Changing the `opacity` of a `CALayer` using the value of a `UISlider`.

I want to do that using a `CABasicAnimation`, what I wrote since now works well but when the slider has a value of 1.0 the opacity turns back to 0.0, while it should be at 1.0 (the final requested value).

Here is the code:

```
// Function called when slider changes values
- (IBAction)sliderDidChangeValue:(id)sender {

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [self fader:1.0 from:0.0];
    anim.timeOffset = ((UISlider*)sender).value;

    // The animatedView gets the new animation with updated timeOffset
    [self.animatedView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"opacity"];
}

// This a simple helper function to create the fade animation
- (CABasicAnimation*)fader:(float)to from:(float)from{

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:from];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:to];
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    anim.speed = 0.0;
    anim.duration = 1.0;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    return anim;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is how `timeOffset` works. The duration remains unchanged, it's just that all the values are shifted around.

The effect you are talking about can (if I remember correctly) be achieved with a negative `beginTime`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify why you want explicit animation using `CABasicAnimation`. It's not necessary here assuming you're just wanting to animate the layer opacity. You can just use implicit animation by setting the opacity directly on `animatedView`'s layer:

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidChangeValue:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat value = ((UISlider*)sender).value;
    self.animatedView.layer.opacity = value;
}
```

Having said that though, you should be aware that it won't actually perform the animation because you are using the root layer of the view. Instead, add another layer to the view hierarchy, and animate it's opacity implicitly instead.

First add the sublayer you're going to animate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _animatedLayer = [CALayer layer];
    _animatedLayer.position = CGPointMake(200.0f, 200.0f);
    _animatedLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f);
    _animatedLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_animatedLayer];

}
```

Then, when the slider changes, implicitly animate the change by setting the value directly and wrap the change in a `CATransaction` so you can control the animation duration.

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidChange:(id)sender
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    self.animatedLayer.opacity = [(UISlider*)sender value];
    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

Remember that when you set a property in an animation, it is not *actually* setting the value in the layer, but rather just showing it in the animation. You have to actually set the value in the layer if you want it to remain. That is why using implicit animation and just setting the property directly is sometimes desirable.

I posted a quick project to Github: https://github.com/perlmunger/FadeViewOpacity.git

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for. I'm not completely sure I understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Great answer! The problem that I face is more complex than what I wrote in this question... This is the simplest scenario that I can encounter with the framework that I'm trying to build. My main problem is that I can't understand why the animation turn back to the initial value when the slider has a value of 1.0.